# Cannot find symbol error in cmd but not in IDE

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile the following code (one of two files I need to complete this homework) but I'm getting 2 errors in cmd. This is what cmd throws at me:

```
CarRentalTest.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        CarRental myCarRental = new CarRental(); //create CarRental object CarRental
        ^
  symbol:   class CarRental
  location: class CarRentalTest
CarRentalTest.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        CarRental myCarRental = new CarRental(); //create CarRental object CarRental
                                    ^
  symbol:   class CarRental
  location: class CarRentalTest
2 errors
```

And this is the code I'm trying to compile.

```
public class CarRentalTest {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        CarRental myCarRental = new CarRental(); //create CarRental object CarRental
        myCarRental.Customers();

    } //end method main

} //end class CarRentalTest
```

What's weird is that the whole thing runs fine in NetBeans. What am I doing wrong here? :9

Comment: Please don't mark blocks as runnable Javascript code snippets when they're not.

Comment: Where is `CarRental` class, is it in the same location or in different package?

Comment: You are not compiling your whole project, your IDE does it automatically for you.

Comment: Sorry about marking it as a code snippet. Can't seem to edit it to correct it but I'll try again soon. CarRental.java and CarRentalTest.java are in same folder. I can only submit these two files from my project so I wanted to make sure they run before I submit them.

Comment: did you **copy paste** the code from the IDE , or **write it again** ?? i find the question important , because IF you wrote it again then you will be missing import CarRental which the IDE would have auto added to your code

Comment: @SrinathGanesh I saved the file from within the IDE.

Comment: @Christn can you provide the exact project structure . what package has what class

Answer (score 6):

> What am I doing wrong here?

Not building `CarRental`, or not telling the compiler where to find the class if you *have* already compiled it. The IDE is probably assuming you want to build everything, so that's fine.

We don't know how your code is organized, but you should *either* pass all the relevant filenames to the compiler at the same time:

```
javac -d classes src\CarRental.java test\CarRentalTest.java
```

... or put the output directory of the earlier compilation in the classpath for the later compilation, e.g.

```
javac -d classes src\CarRental.java
javac -d testclasses -cp classes test\CarRentalTest.java
```

Comment: Thanks for this.

Compiling them at the same time with:
javac CarRental.java CarRentalTest.java compiled them both

Unfortunately, now I'm getting a "Could not find or load main class CarRentalTest" error when trying to run the test.

Comment: @Christn: Well that's a separate question, and one which there are already lots of other questions about.

Comment: Sorry Jon, I think I was just worried that I had done something wrong while compiling and ended up breaking it. Your advice about compiling it together got me rolling on finding an exact solution. I went about it by compiling it as a package:
javac CarRental.java CarRentalTest.java -d rentals

Comment: @Christn: Right, so then you need `java -cp rentals CarRentalTest` or `java -cp rentals foo.bar.CarRentalTest` if you're using a `package`. (It's not clear from the code sample.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a standard directory layout for your project, where production and test code are in separate directory trees then the java command line will not see the production class if your currect directory is the test directory.

To clarify:
Suppose you have this dir structure:

```
src/
  main/
    java/
      mypackage/
        CarRental.java
  test/
    java/
      mypackpage/
        CarRentalTest.java
```

and you are in the 'src/test/java/mypackage/' directory, you would experience this error when running `javac` at the command line - although the production and test classes are in the same package, they are in different directories.

The IDE knows about this directory structure, includes the test path during compilation and therefore it works OK.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't quite sure if I needed to preserve the directory structure so I had two copies. One where both CarRental and CarRentalTest were in the same folder and one where they were in the directory tree from my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import CarRental class in the CarRentalTest.

import yourpackage.CarRental in the CarRentalTest. Java Compiler can't find the CarRental in the CarRentalTest.java.

In the IDE whole package comes in the java file

```
    import package.car.*;
```

This is why it is working in IDE.

Comment: Can you mark it useful or the correct answer if it helped you ?

Comment: If the code compiles in an IDE, it doesn't need to be changed in order to compile from the command line. The problem is the way the code is compiled, not imports.

Comment: It s correct but the question he asked why CarRental is not coming in CarRentalTest.java. As he is compiling the code in the cmd.

Comment: Sorry blackOcean but I don't have enough reputation points to vote it up.

Comment: @JonSkeet I went through the process again without importing it and everything still works. I'm assuming importing is redundant if I'm compiling as a package.

Comment: @blackOcean: And the answer is that it has nothing to do with the imports, and everything to do with the compiler having `CarRentalTest` on the classpath...

Comment: Yes, it will work when you compile the code as a package. It will come in that scope but when you run one java using javac cmd. and Thanks @JonSkeet for correcting me on this thing. I just messed up. Thanks buddy !!!